# Weird spike by subsurf modifier

Tags: subdivision-surface

[image]

I don't understand the reason for this strange spike. I tried to delete faces and edges and reconnect again several times and it's appear no matter what. What is the reason and how to get rid of it?

[Here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsQ0dL4Q15QpgcJkadRxoza3UL15EQ) is a link to .blender file

Comment: Can you post your .blend to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can examine in detail? Most likely there is a stray vertex somewhere causing this. Sometimes modifiers can reveal problems with a mesh that we didn't know existed.

Comment: Added link to the file

Comment: Eventually i find wrong edge that caused it! problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these two vertices/edges that are connected to the faces that you're trying to smooth.  I can only assume they were part of the carryover from your screw modifier.

[image]

Delete them and this is what you get:

[image]